# C# thread exits before receiving data on socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, memorystream

I am trying to send some text over the network using sockets and memory streams. The full data length in my example is 20480 bytes long. Buffer size is 8192.
Before I can receive the last 4096 bytes, the socket receives only 3088 bytes and the whole thread exits without throwing an exception just before receiving the last chunk of data.

```
// Send
while (sentBytes < ms.Length)
{
    if (streamSize < Convert.ToInt64(buffer.Length))
    {
        ms.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(streamSize));
        count = socket.Send(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(streamSize), SocketFlags.None);
        sentBytes += Convert.ToInt64(count);
        streamSize -= Convert.ToInt64(count);
    }
    else
    {
        ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        count = socket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        sentBytes += Convert.ToInt64(count);
        streamSize -= Convert.ToInt64(count);
    }
}

// Receive
while (readBytes < size)
{
    if (streamSize < Convert.ToInt64(buffer.Length))
    // exits after this, before receiving the last 1008 bytes
    {
        count = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(streamSize), SocketFlags.None);
        if (count > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            readBytes += Convert.ToInt64(count);
            streamSize -= Convert.ToInt64(count);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        count = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        if (count > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            readBytes += Convert.ToInt64(count);
            streamSize -= Convert.ToInt64(count);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the exact same algorithm to send/receive files having bigger sizes (over 1 GB) and the transfer works perfectly, no files are corrupted (I use file streams for that).
Interestingly, this code works in the debugger if I add a breakpoint on the sender side.

Also works with this modification:

```
if (streamSize < Convert.ToInt64(buffer.Length))
{
    if (count > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(streamSize));
        readBytes += streamSize;
        streamSize -= streamSize;
    }
}
```

but this comes with no checking on how much data is received and also doesn't work to transfer files.
Could anybody point it out what is going on here?

---

Thread started like this:

```
public ClientConnection(Socket clientSocket, Server mainForm)
{
  this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
  clientThread = new Thread(ReceiveData);
  clientConnected = true;
  this.mainForm = mainForm;
  clientThread.Start(clientSocket);
}
```

**Added from comment by OP**

```
// text is 10240 characters long 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text));
// streamsize is 20480, which is sent prior to text in a header to the receiver 
long streamSize = ms.Length;
```

**Update:**
Tested with more files, now the file transfer fails as well. The problem is with the last 1008 bytes in all cases.

Comment: How are you getting to that bit of code. How are you launching your thread?

Comment: How do you calculate `streamSize`?

Comment: // text is 10240 characters long  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text));
// streamsize is 20480, which is sent prior to text in a header to the receiver  long streamSize = ms.Length;

Comment: @Laz80UK - In the future, please edit your question to add code, as code does not format well in comments and can be hard to read/follow.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. First time user here, thanks for helping me out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found it... When I expected to receive the header, I hadn't prepare the software to receive exactly header sized data.

```
//byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
readBytes = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

This somehow caused a rogue 16 bytes of data written on the socket every time I was receiving the last chunk of the payload, the socket disconnected and the thread exited not throwing any exceptions whatsoever. I hope this answer will help one day someone else running into the same issue. All data transfer works properly now.

Comment: I'm getting something similar in behavior - can someone pls explain what @Laz80UK means by "rogue 16 bytes of data"?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the thread was exiting and not blocked at socket.receive? I see no reason for the thread to exit without any exception

Comment: The thread basically crashed, that is why it threw no exception. Because the socket was expecting 1024 bytes and only 16 was sent, some uninitialized 16 bytes appeared in the buffer, before the thread exited. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the simplified implementation of the functionality using `NetworkStream` class to perform the I/O-operations instead of the `Socket` class: the `NetworkStream` class allows to slightly increase the level of abstraction. An instance of the `NetworkStream` class can be created using an instance of the `Socket` class.

### Sender

The implementation of the Sender is pretty straightforward using the [Stream.CopyTo Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
private static void CustomSend(Stream inputStream, Socket socket)
{
    using (var networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket))
    {
        inputStream.CopyTo(networkStream, BufferSize);
    }
}
```

### Receiver

Let's introduce the following extension methods for the `Stream` class which copies the exact number of bytes from one instance of the `Stream` class to another using the specified buffer:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static bool TryCopyToExact(this Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, byte[] buffer, int bytesToCopy)
    {
        if (inputStream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inputStream");
        }

        if (outputStream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("outputStream");
        }

        if (buffer.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid buffer specified", "buffer");
        }

        if (bytesToCopy <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Bytes to copy must be positive", "bytesToCopy");
        }

        int bytesRead;
        while (bytesToCopy > 0 && (bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(buffer.Length, bytesToCopy))) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesToCopy -= bytesRead;
        }

        return bytesToCopy == 0;
    }

    public static void CopyToExact(this Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, byte[] buffer, int bytesToCopy)
    {
        if (!TryCopyToExact(inputStream, outputStream, buffer, bytesToCopy))
        {
            throw new IOException("Failed to copy the specified number of bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

So, the Receiver can be implemented as follows:

```
private static void CustomReceive(Socket socket)
{
    // It seems your receiver implementation "knows" the "size to receive".
    const int SizeToReceive = 20480;
    var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream(new byte[SizeToReceive], true);
    using (var networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket))
    {
        networkStream.CopyToExact(outputStream, buffer, SizeToReceive);
    }

    // Use the outputStream instance...
}
```

### Important note

Please do not forget to call the `Dispose()` method of the instances of the `Socket` class (for both Sender and Receiver). The absence of the method call can be a root cause of the problems.